# How can I set MySQL server timezone to UTC?

Tags: mysql

I have added this line `default_time_zone='+00:00'` into */etc/my.cnf*, but I get this error message when restart server:

```
error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/my.cnf
```

**UPDATE**

```
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

default_time_zone = "+00:00"

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
```

Comment: please post the relevant section of your cnf. Looks like you're mssing a [] group

Comment: this line should inserted into a certain "section"?? like i.e. [mysql]??

Comment: I posted the answer, yes it's not part of a group, hence the error, move it down to under the [mysqld] and change the underscores to dashes (default-time-zone instead of default_time_zone)

Comment: I used underscore, and it was accepted, and used now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to `default-time-zone=` from default_time_zone and place it in the `[mysqld]` section of your cnf

Comment: This causes my mysql server to stop starting under WSL.  Doesn't seem to matter what I set it to, 'UTC' or 'Europe/Helsinki' same thing.

Comment: To address my own issue, this was caused by not having the named timezones loaded into the server.  Notice that you need to run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot -p mysql` to populate these tables manually. Be sure you specify the mysql schema at the end of your mysql cmd.